# Blender 3.4-3.5 running up to 2x slower on Ubuntu 22.04 then on Windows 10

Tags: cycles-render-engine, windows

I have purchased a lenovo legion pro with this specs:

- Intel i7 12700,
- nVidia 3070,
- RAM 16gb

I have Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10 dual boot.

In Windows, Blender works great, BMW demo scene, on GPU rendering takes for about 11 seconds.
In Ubuntu, the same BMW scene renders in 20-22 seconds.

The same goes for other demo scenes too.

- Classroom in Ubuntu renders in 48 seconds, Windows 29 seconds.
- Barbershop - Ubuntu - 3:21 min, Win - 2:00 min.

Ubuntu has installed fresh proprietary drivers 525 for nVidia card.

I was wondering if any of you knows how to make Blender run faster on Ubuntu then on Windows?
As I know, Blender is supposed to run better on Linux then on any other OS, but maybe I am making a mistake.

Comment: 3.5 is a recent release, you could make a report as a Bug with the demos using the Blender Help menu > Report Bug. Also, this looks like a discussion kind of topic than a Blender Question. You could try blenderartists or Blender on reddit

Comment: Thank you Emir for the fast reply. I will do that now.
But, just to mention that Blender 3.4 had the same issue before it got automatically updated to 3.5.